# incomplete netcdf files from OpenNex PlanetOS web

Tags: netcdf, climate

I've been trying to download netcdf files of the NASA NEX-GDDP downscaled GCMs dataset from http://opennex.planetos.com/ website. Right now I'm trying to download 7 GCMs historical/projected data for the RCP scenarios 4.5 and 8.5 of all Central America.

I've already run the docker from different local and cloud servers (no AWS yet), but it seems that all times the netcdf file I get is incomplete (~ 3.2 gb). I've checked the file by opening it in Panoply and mapping some of the variables but many of them don't show data.

Does anyone know if there is a better way in which I can check the integrity of a netcdf file?

In case someone wants to try, the command to download the data is:

```
curl -sS http://opennex.planetos.com/p/dZLAD | bash /dev/stdin -a -f nc
```

Comment: Does anyone who has any tutorials on how to download the GCMs data as a csv file? As i am the beginner to get to know this thing, it is very hard for me to understand by myself. Therefore, your help is really appreciated? :) Best Wishes and Regards,

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/137339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @dobrych comment I was able to download the GCMs data as a csv file.

First I launched the data access server with:

```
curl -sS http://opennex.planetos.com/p/dZLAD | bash
```

Then I got the csv with:

```
curl http://localhost:7645/data.csv > output.csv
```

After some hours of downloading I finally got a 77gb file with all the data requested.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that the docker-based command doesn't output any netCDF data into the shell pipeline. It does launch local docker instance with the configuration you've created via the Web UI.

Here is stdout actually looks like
https://gist.github.com/dobrych/2cf416d05608c30851f9f7d325d3de19

Since most of the users were interested in getting data as CVS which is a bit simpler for analysis than NetCDF (which requires a bit of additional tooling), our docker process output is set to CSV by default.

But if you substitute `data.csv` to `data.nc` in the local docker-based URL, it will generate NetCDF, but unlike CSV it doesn't support streaming so it will fetch all the OpenNEX chunks from S3 first, so it will take much longer before any output happens.

Comment: Following your suggestion I'll try to download the data as csv and will keep the question open for any updates. As it's such a large area I imagine the csv file will be huge. Thanks for your answer.